# Why does -1 >> 1 and 0xFFFFFFFF >> 1 produce different results?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to make a test to tell whether my PC performs arithmetic or logical right shift by right-shifting hexadecimal `FFFFFFFF` by `1`.

I know that an integer `-1` reads as `FFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal since it is the two's complement of `1`.  Right-shifting `-1` by `1` results in `FFFFFFFF` and shows the PC performed arithmetic right shift.

But if I just type in `0xFFFFFFFF >> 1`, it resulted in `7FFFFFFF` and shows that the PC performed logical right shift instead.  Why did that happen?  See for the code below that produced the results:

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    printf ( "%x >> 1 = %x\n", -1, -1 >> 1 );
    printf ( "%x >> 1 = %x\n", 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff >> 1 );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program's output was:

```
ffffffff >> 1 = ffffffff
ffffffff >> 1 = 7fffffff
```

Comment: `-1` is signed.  `0xffffffff` is unsigned.  It has nothing to do with `printf()`.

Comment: right shifting negative signed values is implementation defined: `-1 >> 1` could print as `7fffffff` as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not an assumption. What *type* do you think `0xffffffff` is ? According to the C standard, **6.4.4.1 Integer constants**, the *type* of the expression of a *hexadecimal* constant (preceded with `0x`) is the first of the following which can applicably hold the represented value:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

On your platform, 0xFFFFFFFF cannot be represented as `int` because `int` is 32 bits and only 31 bits express quantity in `signed int` (the standard dictates one bit is reserved for sign). The next type, `unsigned int`, is therefore used. Therefore no sign bit is present to extended with the shift operation, which is thereby logical rather than arithmetic.

It may not be apparent how I concluded `int` was 32 bits on your platform. Indeed I could not make that assumption were it not for the *first* line, which arithmetic-right-shifts the value of `-1`. The result of that shift, dumped as `%x`, was `0xFFFFFFFF`. Had `int` been native 64-bits that should dump `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` instead. Without that prior knowledge, no single type conclusion of `0xFFFFFFFF` could be assumed since it may well be representable as a standard signed `int` of width 64-bits (63+1) with value `0x00000000FFFFFFFF`. The resulting shift would produce the same output you see now, thereby introducing an alternative to that postulated above.

Answer (score 6):

Your main question is: is `0xffffffff` unsigned?

From C11 §6.4.4.1 Integer constants

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
>   be represented.
>
> [image]

The output of your first `printf` line suggests that `int` is 32-bit on your machine. Thus it can not represent `0xffffffff`, it must be unsigned.

Comment: There is nothing in this graph that leads 0xffffffff is `unsigned`. It is OP's `-1` that drives the conclusion.

Comment: @chux I get your point and you are right. But I don't think when OP asks if it's an unsigned integer, he means the type `unsigned` (i.e, `unsigned int`) exactly. I think he means the unsigned types in general, i.e, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`. That's why I didn't use the code format *`unsigned`*, only  *unsigned*.

Comment: `0xffffffff` could be `int` (aka `signed int`) should `int` be 64-bit.  Given the C spec. `0xffffffff`  must be `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int` or `unsigned long int`.