# Bit-shift not applying to a variable declaration-assignment one-liner

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm seeing strange behavior when I try to apply a right bit-shift within a variable declaration/assignment:

```
unsigned int i = ~0 >> 1;
```

The result I'm getting is `0xffffffff`, as if the `>> 1` simply wasn't there. It seems to be something about the `~0`, because if I instead do:

```
unsigned int i = 0xffffffff >> 1;
```

I get `0x7fffffff` as expected. I thought I might be tripping over an operator precedence issue, so tried:

```
unsigned int i = (~0) >> 1;
```

but it made no difference. I could just perform the shift in a separate statement, like

```
unsigned int i = ~0;
i >>= 1;
```

but I'd like to know what's going on.

*update* Thanks merlin2011 for pointing me towards an answer. Turns out it was performing an arithmetic shift because it was interpreting `~0` as a signed (negative) value. The simplest fix seems to be:

```
unsigned int i = ~0u >> 1;
```

Now I'm wondering why `0xffffffff` wasn't also interpreted as a signed value.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7632/391161).

Comment: @merlin2011 Ah, this answer lower down on that page has the cause: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10101/1631106

Comment: your first mistake is assuming that `~0` means `0xffffffff`

Comment: @M.M I wouldn't call it an assumption. I tested it out on my machine to see if that was the case.

Comment: @ivan it is quite strange behavior to see the result in your machine. Things are going well on mine. Is your machine 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Ian It's 32-bit. os x macbook air from 2013/14

Comment: @ivan mine is 64-bit. I cannot really test here, but just to be safe, how about putting `0ul` instead of  `0u`? Is the result the same?

Comment: @ivan according to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence the (type) cast and the `~` is of the same precedence. Just to be very sure, you could also put bracket on your casting.

Comment: @Ian I tried `0ul` and it generates a compiler warning: `implicit conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' changes value from 9223372036854775807 to 4294967295`. The output I then get is `0xffffffff`

Comment: @ivan and what happen if you put bracket? `~(0u)` because everything is ok in my computer, whether I put `u` or `ul`, with or without bracket. Any optimizer you use in your IDE? I use `CodeBlocks`

Comment: @Ian If I use `~(0u)` it works, just as `~0u` did. I'm not using an ide. Just vim and gcc in the terminal.

Comment: @ivan the fact that `~0 >> 1` and `0xffffffff >> 1` give different results proves that `~0` and `0xffffffff` are different

Comment: @M.M It seems like `0xffffffff` is unsigned, but can you explain or point me toward some relevant documentation?

Comment: @ivan see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666567/why-does-1-1-and-0xffffffff-1-produce-different-results)

Comment: @M.M Ah, I think I see what you're getting at now. Though `~0` and `0xffffffff` have the same underlying bit representation, `~0` is the one's compliment of a signed int 0 (so -1), while `0xffffffff` is a positive integer too large to store in a signed int (on my machine, at least), and thus unsigned. I hope I got that right. Thanks :)

Comment: Also note that right shifting negative signed values is implementation defined: `-1 >> 1` could print as `7fffffff` as well on a different environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how c compiler works for signed value. The base literal for number in C is `int` (in 32-bit machine, it is 32-bit signed `int`)

You may want to change it to:

```
unsigned int i = ~(unsigned int)0 >> 1;
```

The reason is because for the signed value, the compiler would treat the operator `>>` as an arithmetic shift (or [signed shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)).

Or, more shortly (pointed out by [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m)),

```
unsigned int i = ~0u >> 1;
```

Test:

```
printf("%x", i);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `~0u >> 1` is another way to write the same thing

Answer (score 0):

In `unsigned int i = ~0;`, `~0` is seen as a signed integer (the compiler should warn about that).

Try this instead:

```
unsigned int i = (unsigned int)~0 >> 1;
```